# Best setup for c++ template/generic/metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, generics

I am writing/maintaining some heavily templated code in c++. I am currently compiling it on windows but it is getting slower to compile and harder to write.

I want to know if there are any

1. Tools
2. Other Compilers
3. Compiler Switch
4. IDE
5. Practice
6. Dependency Management Technique
7. Libraries

on Windows/Linux that can help to work on heavily templated code more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i use:

- gcc 4.4/4.5 and/or icc 11.x
- `-O0 -Wall -g`
- emacs (TOO much to say)
- boost mpl/type_traits/fusion/phoenix
- `boost::mpl::print` is a god's gift
- `BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG`
- boost preprocessor: http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html
- tyeof/auto: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/typeof.html
- result_of: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of

Comment: `-Wall -Werror` just in case I don't want to look at the compilation output :)

Answer (score 2):

If possible, upgrade your compiler. I don't have much experience with Windows, but the upgrade from gcc 4.x to gcc 4.5 is noticeably faster for projects that [make heavy use](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2010/03/faster-meta-programs-using-gcc-45-and.html) of templates.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler are you using now?  Various compilers have different quality template support and error messages.  Clang and Intel tend to be pretty good; GCC usually prints out the necessary information but it is often hard to read.  Visual Studio has nice formatting and is fairly compliant.  In terms of speed, GCC 4.6 is claimed to be much faster than earlier versions.  You might want to download [STLfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) to make the errors easier to read.  Boost (especially Boost.MPL) is a good library for doing template metaprograms; you might also want Boost.Fusion and/or Boost.Proto depending on what you are doing.

Comment: especially on the context of templates, I would not qualify Visual Studio of being *fairly compliant*. Templates are definitely not where Visual Studio shines.